# How to move ImageView

Tags: android

```
    public class AndroidAnim extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
boolean b=false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
    final AnimationDrawable myAnimation1;

    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);
    imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);

    myAnimation1 = (AnimationDrawable) imageView1.getBackground();

    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            myAnimation1.start();
            imageView2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.effect_in));
            }
                         }
    });
```

}
}
I use this code trying move 2 ImageView. More clearly I want when I click on screen, move ImageView one after another (first time moving imageView1, after that have to move imageView2)
Sorry for my english.

Comment: check it http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe AnimationListener could help you out?

Implement it:

```
implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, AnimationListener {
```

Setup the animations:

```
Animation effectIn;
// in onCreate()
effectIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.effect_in);
effectIn.setAnimationListener(this);
```

When the one animation ends, you trigger the other:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(animation == effectIn){
        // start effectOut or whatever.
    }
```

if you want the animations to stay/stop the way they end, use this:

```
effectIn.setFillAfter(true);
```

Or declare it in XML:

```
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

Hope this helps!